# django, how to access form radio button from template

Tags: django

New to Django, I have a app called exposure:

I have a form:

```
usersegment = [['adminLevel0','Admin Level 0'],['adminLevel1','Admin Level 1'], ['adminLevel2','Admin Level 2']]

class ExposureForm(forms.Form):
    adminLevel = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=usersegment)
```

I have a view:

```
def exposure_form(request):
        if request.method =='GET':
                form = ExposureForm()
                return render_to_response('exposure-export-wizard.html')
        else:
                html = '<html><body>Your request cannot be processed</body></html>'
                return HttpResponse(html)
```

and I have template (not working):

```
<form action="/exposure_form/" method="get">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
```

Question is how can I access my radio buttons from the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render the template to context

```
def exposure_form(request):
    if request.method =='GET':
        form = ExposureForm()
        return render_to_response('exposure-export-wizard.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)))
```

More documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response).

Comment: I would make

    `usersegment = [['adminLevel0','Admin Level 0'],['adminLevel1','Admin Level 1'], ['adminLevel2','Admin Level 2']]`

Immutable objects (Tuples) for performance

`usersegment = (('adminLevel0','Admin Level 0'), ('adminLevel1','Admin Level 1'), ('adminLevel2','Admin Level 2'))`